# A few formatting questions regarding WPF LiveCharts HeatSeries

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, heatmap, livecharts

I used LiveCharts' `HeatSeries` control to create a climate chart in my WPF application (using MVVM / Caliburn.Micro). The chart is populated in my ViewModel which is working as intended but I'm having a few issues formatting that I can't seem to resolve and both AI and their documentation haven't been helpful. I've highlighted the issues in the screenshot below.

[image]

1. How can I change the font size of the axis labels?
2. The chart includes a massive white space to its right. The next grid column starts at "Hello". How can this be fixed?
3. The lower part of the x-axis labels is cut off regardless of margins, row height and chart height.
4. How do I get rid of the colour legend?

XAML:

```
<lvc:CartesianChart Series="{Binding HeatMapSeries}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Margin="10" LegendLocation="None">
    <lvc:CartesianChart.AxisX>
        <lvc:Axis LabelFormatter="{Binding XAxisLabelFormatter}" >
            <lvc:Axis.Separator>
                <lvc:Separator Step="1" />
            </lvc:Axis.Separator>
        </lvc:Axis>
    </lvc:CartesianChart.AxisX>
    <lvc:CartesianChart.AxisY>
        <lvc:Axis Labels="{Binding YAxisLabels}"/>
    </lvc:CartesianChart.AxisY>
</lvc:CartesianChart>
```

Comment: Typically it's best practice to break up questions such that you are asking one question per post. It seems from your code that they layout issues are likely coming from your Grid setup or perhaps the other controls. I made a few suggestions for how to test that in my answer, and I also provided a solution with the layout working correctly. If that doesn't help, update your question to include more of the xaml so that we can see what else might be affecting the layout issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can format the axis labels simply by adding font size, weight, etc properties within the label itself:

For Example:

```xml
<lvc:Axis Labels="{Binding SalesMan}" LabelsRotation="-15" FontSize="18" FontWeight="Bold">
```

I am not sure if there is a way to explicitly remove the gradient legend. There is a kind of hacky workaround by way of setting `Margin="0,0,-17,0"` to clip the gradient map legend out of view, where 17 is about the space I want to clip. Not great, but it does work. If I find another way, I will update the answer accordingly, but for now, it seems built-in.

```xml
<lvc:CartesianChart Series="{Binding HeatMapSeries}" Margin="0,0,-17,0" Padding="10" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" LegendLocation="None">
```

For your formatting issues (extra space and clipping), there is probably something wrong with your grid layout. It might be a good idea to try getting rid of the chart and using some `Border` Controls to get a sense for how things are laying out.

To help you get started there, here is a working example with the layout working correctly, which borrows heavily from the [LiveCharts example code](https://v0.lvcharts.com/App/examples/v1/Wpf/Heat%20Series):

```xml
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Button Grid.Row="0" Click="ButtonBase_OnClick" Margin="10">Randomize</Button>
    <lvc:CartesianChart Grid.Row="1" DataTooltip="{x:Null}" LegendLocation="None" Margin="0,0,-17,0">
        <lvc:CartesianChart.Series>
            <lvc:HeatSeries Values="{Binding Values}" DataLabels="True" />
        </lvc:CartesianChart.Series>
        <lvc:CartesianChart.AxisX>
            <lvc:Axis Labels="{Binding SalesMan}" LabelsRotation="-45" FontSize="18" FontWeight="Bold">
                <lvc:Axis.Separator>
                    <lvc:Separator Step="1"></lvc:Separator>
                </lvc:Axis.Separator>
            </lvc:Axis>
        </lvc:CartesianChart.AxisX>
        <lvc:CartesianChart.AxisY>
            <lvc:Axis Labels="{Binding Days}" FontSize="18"></lvc:Axis>
        </lvc:CartesianChart.AxisY>
    </lvc:CartesianChart>

    <TextBlock Text="Hello" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Background="White" />

    <TextBlock Text="More stuff down here...." Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="2" />
</Grid>
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I've made it work somehow but it does feel hacky. That massive white space is still there but a negative margin value takes care of that as well.

Comment: I'm glad that helped! I still think the white space has something to do with the grid columns. I will usually change background colors and/add borders temporarily just to see what is taking up the space in these sorts of situations. Spacing on wpf can be tricky.